# Deselect a JTree

Tags: java, swing, jtree, deselect

I have a `JPanel` containing 8 different `JTrees`, each one of them in a `JScrollPane`.

When I click on a tree node, it got always selected even if I select a different tree. So the situation could be the following:

[image]

My simple goal is to deselect a tree when I click on another one.

I already solved this problem but not in an efficient and elegant way, doing this for **each** tree:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(treeONE);
    treeONE.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            treeTWO.clearSelection();
            treeTHREEC.clearSelection();
            treeFOUR.clearSelection();
            treeFIVE.clearSelection();
            treeSIX.clearSelection();
            treeSEVEN.clearSelection();
            treeEIGHT.clearSelection();
        }
    });
    add(scrollPane);
```

Is there a better way to code this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define an array containing all your trees:

```
JTree[] allTrees = {
    treeONE, treeTWO, treeTHREE, treeFOUR, treeFIVE, treeSIX, treeSEVEN, treeEIGHT
};
```

Then you can use the same `MouseListener` instance for all your trees:

```
MouseListener mouseListenerForAllTrees = new MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        // deselect all trees except the one which fired the event
        for (JTree tree : allTrees) {
            if (tree != e.getSource())
                tree.clearSelection();
        }
    }
};
for (JTree tree : allTrees) {
    tree.addMouseListener(mouseListenerForAllTrees);
}
```

Comment: for loop to add listeners would also be better.

Comment: @SergiyMedvynskyy You are right. I have updated my answer.